# Singletons are know to be bad-practice, angular is based on singletons. Is angular bad?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, singleton

All the services in Angular are singletons. Singletons are known to be bad practice.

I know that many people (Including me) are very happy with Angular.
What am I missing here?

Comment: It sounds more like logical fallacy rather than a real question.

Comment: That is a rather bold statement based on opinion.  I dont think every developer would agree that Singletons are bad.  When used properly, they can be quite useful (my opinion).

Comment: your comparison is wrong! singletons solve only one problem where angular services come into play for resource contention.

Comment: Singleton != Single Instance

Answer (score 4):

Singleton is a super useful pattern. It's hard to imagine building  software without it! Imagine, for example, constantly recreating an object that hashes a million records.

The problems lie in the implementation:

[What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

> They are generally used as a global instance, why is that so bad?
> Because you hide the dependencies of your application in your
> code,instead of exposing them through the interfaces. Making something
> global to avoid passing it around is a code smell.
>
> They violate the single responsibility principle: by virtue of the
> fact that they control their own creation and lifecycle.
>
> They inherently cause code to be tightly coupled. This makes faking
> them out under test rather difficult in many cases.
>
> They carry state around for the lifetime of the application. Another
> hit to testing since you can end up with a situation where tests need
> to be ordered which is a big no no for unit tests. Why? Because each
> unit test should be independent from the other.

The bulk of the criticism would seem to be pointed at a very old-fashioned implementation of the singleton pattern, where they are available globally:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Using a dependency injection container (like angular or spring) overcomes most of the above objections.  The container handles life-cycle and injecting the singleton instance into client code.  You can always replace the injected singleton with a different one for testing purposes.

In short, using a DI container makes it easy to use singletons without the potential bad effects.